# Tkinter: Color Chooser on MacOS

Tags: python, macos, tkinter, colors

The Python Tkinter color chooser does not work in Python Version 3.8.5 on Mac.
Whenever I type in `colorchooser.askcolor()`, It always outputs `Traceback (most recent call last): File "<pyshell#5>", line 1, in <module> colorchooser.askcolor() NameError: name 'colorchooser' is not defined`.
I did this all in the shell and I didn't forget to add `from tkinter import *`. Could you please help me?

Comment: Are you writing your code into a .py file, or writing in your IDE's shell?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`import` as:

```
from tkinter.colorchooser import askcolor
```

and you can direct use,

```
askcolor(color=None, **options)
```

Comment: It didn't work, for some reason it printed out `SyntaxError: multiple statements found while compiling a single statement` and if I tried it the other way, it printed out `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
    askcolor(color=None, **options)
NameError: name 'options' is not defined`

Comment: check [this](https://www.pythontutorial.net/tkinter/tkinter-color-chooser/). -@HackerCookie

Answer (score 1):

Some modules reqiure you to do `from tkinter import x`, and do not get imported with `from tkinter import *`. Add `from tkinter import colorchooser` into your code.

Comment: I did `from tkinter import colorchooser` then on the next line, I added `colorchooser.askcolor()` All it did was open the `tk` in the python rocket app, but I have to admit, it certainly is closer.